# Is there a way to include dynamically html in partial views in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, partial-views

I wonder what is the correct approach to achieve this? I have an "overview" of products and other stuff it's in the "view"-file of the controller. I want to show product-items in a list on an overview page, but in other templates as well (*same html-elements but with different values for each product*). I don't want to type same thing twice and want to easily maintain the code.

I have this file *(views/profile/overview.php*) it's basically a for-each loop listing of products - something like:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item->name;
    echo $item->creation_date;
}
```

**Is there a way to put**

```
 echo $item->name;
 echo $item->creation_date;
```

**in a single partial view** (like product_item) and load that dynamically?

I've tried: (does not work because $item is undefined in product_item)

```
foreach($items as $item) {
        $this->load->view('/profile/partials/product_item');
}
```

**Try 2:** (didn't work either. I don't know why - because $item should be passed to that view?)

```
foreach($items as $item) {
       $this->load->view('/profile/partials/product_item', $item);
}
```

**Try 3:** (same as try 2)

```
foreach($items as $item) {
       $x = $this->load->view('/profile/partials/product_item', $item);
       echo $x;
}
```

**Try 4** (I've tried to do this in controller (I then just wanted to echo out `$product_item` into the overview-template)

```
$this->view_data['product_item'] = $this->load->view('profile/partials/product_item', $this->view_data, true);
```

I have to mention that product_item and it's html is far more code than this, I just wanted to describe my issue. If you need more, please tell me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load->view()` takes an associative array or an object as a parameter, so this should work:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    $this->load->view('/profile/partials/product_item', array('item' => $item));
}
```

After that, you can use:

```
echo $item->name;
echo $item->creation_date;
```

in your view.

---

Remember, every array key of the array/object that you pass to your load view function becomes a variable in the view. So, if you send:

```
$data['hey'] = 'there';
```

In your view, you'll have the variable `$hey` which has the value `'there'`.

Comment: Damn, thats alot of edits.  I feel like I should make some of my own now lol

Comment: @Philip Haha, once you start... I wanted to explain what should work and what shouldn't and why. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope I managed to explain what happens there.

Answer (score 3):

To Build on what @Shomz as just said

### Master Template

*views/master/template.php*

Say you load in your Product Controller View

```
<section role="content">
    <?php echo $this->load->view($view); ?>
</section>
```

But What if you then want to load some more information from the Product Controller, in say the sidebar?

---

Well you can do so from the Product Controller, and simple do a Conditional to check if the variable was sent back from the Controller.

```
<aside role="sidebar">
    <section>
         //Normal sidebar stuff here, nothing to worry about
    </section>

    <?php if($sidebar) : ?> //Did ANY Controller send a Sidebar Variable ?
    <section >
       <?php echo $this->load->view($sidebar); ?>
    </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
</aside>
```

### Controller

```
public function someMethod()
{
    $this->template = 'master/template'; //views/master/template

    return $this->load->view($this->template, array(
          'view'   =>  'products/index' // the $view var
          'sidebar' => $this->load->view('partials/sidebar', array('product_data'=>$model), true) //$sidebar var buffered with dynamic data
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this may be a response to a dated question; but in addition to @Philip's answer, the [CodeIgniter Template Parser Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html#view-fragments) can be used to prevent the 'contamination' of the view files with PHP code.

An example with the iteration controlled in the controller, using a view fragment:

```
$temp = '';
$template1 = '<li><a href="{link}">{title}</a></li>';
$data1 = array(
        array('title' => 'First Link', 'link' => '/first'),
        array('title' => 'Second Link', 'link' => '/second'),
);

foreach ($data1 as $menuitem)
{
        $temp .= $this->parser->parse_string($template1, $menuitem, TRUE);
}

$template = '<ul>{menuitems}</ul>';
$data = array(
        'menuitems' => $temp
);
$this->parser->parse_string($template, $data);
```

Result:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="/first">First Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="/second">Second Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

A further tutorial is avaialble at [Introduction to Templating and Dynamic Views with Codeigniter](http://www.innovativephp.com/introduction-to-templating-and-dynamic-views-with-codeigniter/).